# Approximation of a function with Laguerre Polynomials.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I have this orthonormal system of polynomials:
$$L_{n}(x):=\frac{e^{x}}{n!}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(e^{-x}x^{n})$$
And I suppose that this is a basis in $L^{2}(0,+\infty)$ endowed whit the s.p. $(u,v):=\int_{0}^{\infty}u(x)v(x)e^{-x}dx$.

I have to compute the polynomial of degree $\leq 2$ which approximate the function
$$f(x)=e^{x/4}$$
In $L^{2}(0,+\infty)$ endowed with the above defined s.p. $(u,v)$.

Any suggestion to start? Thank you very much.

Comment: You know it's orthonormal, you know the scalar product, you (hopefully) know how to calculate the coefficients as scalar products $a_i=(f, L_i)$, and you need just the first three of them, for $i=0, 1, 2$. So where's the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know $L_{0}(x)=1$, $L_{1}(x)=-x+1$ and $L_{2}(x)=1/2(x^{2})-2x+1$. I think that these are the three terms you talking about. Thank you :).